# Python not recognizing installed dependencies

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am running Python version 2.7.12 a windows system without internet access and have manually installed modules. However when trying to run a script requiring matplotlib.pyplot and after installing the dependencies `dateutil` it is still not working.

[image]

I am still receiving the error:

[image]

What is the reason for the error? I have been troubleshooting the problem for  a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Pip to install the package. You can download a copy of dateutil 2.5.3 from here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/2.5.3.

Once downloaded, navigate to the folder where you downloaded the dateutil package, and install the package with pip:

```
pip install python_dateutil-2.5.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

After the module is installed, simply import as normal in the console or script:

```
import dateutil
```

And here is a quick example:

[image: Installing module using pip]

If you need to install pip, here are [some instruction to install pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).